# jQuery UI sortable placeholder appears in incorrect position, but only on first on-hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am experiencing a bug regarding the initial positioning of jQuery UI's sortable placeholder when I drag an item from one sortable to another, connected sortable.

Here's a picture showing the placeholder appearing one index position above where it should. Note that Item3 on the RHS list is below the placeholder, but I my pointer was fully below Item3 when the placeholder appeared:

[image]

The position fixes itself once the helper is dragged a bit more, but causes some ugly flickering. Note that if I drag my helper out of the RHS list and then drag it back into the RHS list -- no flicker occurs. It is ONLY on the first time it enters.

[Here's a working example of the issue](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/sjFHe)

and here's the code referenced in the link:

```
//  HTML:
<div class='sortable-list'>
    <div class='sortable-list-item'>Item1</div>
    <div class='sortable-list-item'>Item2</div>
    <div class='sortable-list-item'>Item3</div>
</div>
<div class='sortable-list'>
    <div class='sortable-list-item'>Item1</div>
    <div class='sortable-list-item'>Item2</div>
    <div class='sortable-list-item'>Item3</div>
</div>

// CSS:
.sortable-list {
    border: solid 1px black;
    height: 250px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
}

.sortable-list-item {
    border: solid 1px red;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
}

.sortable-placeholder {
    background-color: #ebebeb;
}

//  JS:
var sortlists = $('.sortable-list').sortable({
  tolerance: 'pointer',
  connectWith: '.sortable-list',
  placeholder: 'sortable-placeholder sortable-list-item'
});
```

Looking for a confirmation that this is a bug with jQuery UI or a correction to my CSS, but I don't see any.

**UPDATE 1:**

Here's a screencast of me reproducing the issue on Chrome 33 beta: http://screencast.com/t/cAV6xYXWUO

Comment: when I try it out in you sample, it seems to work. I  tested this in chrome...

Comment: What version of Chrome? I'm on 33.0.1750.29 beta-m, but I've seen the issue for a while now. I can take a small screencast if that helps? Let me see if it reproduces in FF, too.

Comment: Seems to work for me, `Chrome Version 32.0.1700.76 m`

Comment: version: Version 32.0.1700.76 m

Comment: Humm. I just installed non-beta, but I'm still getting v33. Are you guys up to date? I'm on Windows 7, but Omaha says current is v32, so maybe I'm in the wrong: http://omahaproxy.appspot.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am able to reproduce this problem in my chrome (32.0.1700.76)

One way of correcting it is to just add an empty div to the end of your lists. The bug will still occur, but it won't be visible to the user at all:

```
<div class='sortable-list'>
    <div class='sortable-list-item'>Item1</div>
    <div class='sortable-list-item'>Item2</div>
    <div class='sortable-list-item'>Item3</div>
    <div></div>
</div>
<div class='sortable-list'>
    <div class='sortable-list-item'>Item1</div>
    <div class='sortable-list-item'>Item2</div>
    <div class='sortable-list-item'>Item3</div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a pretty genius solution. I'll give it a spin.

Comment: Kudos to you @Joel. This genius solution still works :D